# redeclared as different kind of entity #ESP8266 #line array digital sensor

Tags: arduino, compiler-errors, arduino-esp8266

When I tried to show the output of the digital sensors but the code is not compiling. This same code worked in ESp32. But I don't where I redeclared 's8'.

This is my code:

```
//const int digital_pin_1 = 16;//D0
const int digital_pin_2 = 5;//D1
const int digital_pin_3 = 4;//D2
const int digital_pin_4 = 0;//D3
const int digital_pin_5 = 2;//D4
const int digital_pin_6 = 14;//D5 
const int digital_pin_7 = 12;//D6
const int digital_pin_8 = 13;//D7

int s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
//  pinMode(digital_pin_1,INPUT);
  pinMode(digital_pin_2,INPUT);
  pinMode(digital_pin_3,INPUT);
  pinMode(digital_pin_4,INPUT);
  pinMode(digital_pin_5,INPUT);
  pinMode(digital_pin_6,INPUT);
  pinMode(digital_pin_7,INPUT);
  pinMode(digital_pin_8,INPUT);
}

void loop(){
  Serial.println("s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7,s8");
//  s1 = digitalRead(digital_pin_1);
  s2 = digitalRead(digital_pin_2);
  s3 = digitalRead(digital_pin_3);
  s4 = digitalRead(digital_pin_4);
  s5 = digitalRead(digital_pin_5);
  s6 = digitalRead(digital_pin_6);
  s7 = digitalRead(digital_pin_7);
  s8 = digitalRead(digital_pin_8);
 // Serial.print(String(s1)+",  ");
  Serial.print(String(s2)+",  ");
  Serial.print(String(s3)+",  ");
  Serial.print(String(s4)+",  ");
  Serial.print(String(s5)+",  ");
  Serial.print(String(s6)+",  ");
  Serial.print(String(s7)+",  ");
  Serial.print(String(s8)+", \n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the full error message:

> In file included from
> C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4\cores\esp8266/esp8266_peri.h:24:0,
> from C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4\cores\esp8266/Arduino.h:38,
> from C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_22617\sketch\MyESPSketch.ino.cpp:1:
> C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4/tools/sdk/include/c_types.h:44:29:
> error: previous declaration of 'typedef signed char s8'  typedef
> signed char         s8;

Hint: Easiest choose a better variable name